# Unterschied zwischen "sich ausmalen" und "sich vorstellen"

Tags: word-choice

> **sich etw. vorstellen**: *sich in bestimmter Weise ein Bild von etwas machen*
>
> **sich etw. ausmalen**: **a.** *anschaulich darstellen, schildern*
>                             **b.** *sich etwas in allen Einzelheiten vorstellen*

Aus dem Duden.

Gibt es einen bestimmten Unterschied zwischen den Verben oder sie sind austauschbar?

Comment: Der Duden beschreibt doch den Unterschied: *sich etw. ausmalen* ist detaillierter, bildlicher ....

Comment: Bei "ausmalen" schwingt auch mit, dass man phantasiert oder sich etwas ausdenkt. Zum Beispiel: Ich male mir aus, wie es in meiner neuen Wohnung sein wird; das heißt: ich weiß es nicht, aber ich stelle mir bildlich und detailliert vor, wie es werden könnte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sich etwas ausmalen ist aus meiner Sicht intensiver und manchmal sich übertrieben etwas vorstellen.

Answer (score 2):

*Sich etwas vorstellen* ist aus meiner Sicht relativ abstrakt, bzw. neutral. Es geht um den Vorgang, im Geiste eine Situation, ein Gefühl, etc. zu betrachten.

*Sich etwas ausmalen* bezeichnet eine detailliertere, ausgeschmücktere Form von "sich etwas vorstellen". Wer sich etwas ausmalt, stellt es sich natürlich auch vor, aber bildlicher, meist emotionaler, er taucht tiefer ein.

Daher sind die beiden Ausdrücke nicht synonym. Jemand der sich etwas ausmalt, stellt es sich zwar vor, aber jemand, der sich etwas vorstellt, malt es sich nicht unbedingt auch aus.

Comment: Sich etwas ausmalen ist eine Teilmenge, von sich etwas vorstellen. Daher ist es Unsinn zu sagen, dass die Teilmenge mehr/detaillierter, ausgeschmückter ist als die Gesamtmenge, denn sie ist ja ein Teil dieser.

Comment: Nein, Dein Kommentar ist aus meiner Sicht Unsinn. Erstens entspricht meine Antwort ziemlich genau der Definition im Duden, falls man diesen als Autorität sehen will. Zweitens sprechen wir hier nicht von mathematischen Mengen. Man kann sich etwas einfach nur vorstellen, oder man kann es sich im Detail und lebhaft vorstellen (ausmalen). Klar stellt man sich in beiden Fällen etwas vor, aber daraus ergibt sich noch keine Relation. Genauso könnte man auch argumentieren, dass *sich vorstellen* eine Teilmenge von *sich ausmalen* ist - nämlich einfach die weniger detailreiche/ausgeschmückte.

Comment: Zudem zeichnen sich Teilmengen von Mengen oftmals gerade durch besondere Eigenschaften aus und daher ist es Unsinn zu behaupten, eine Teilmenge von "sich vorstellen" könnte sich nicht dadurch auszeichnen, dass die Vorstellung detailreicher und "bunter" ist. Tiefseefische sind auch Fische, zeichnen sich im Gegensatz zu den anderen Fischen aber dadurch aus, dass sie eben in der Tiefsee leben. Schwarzweiß-Fotos sind auch Fotos, setzen sich aber von anderen Fotos dadurch ab, dass sie keine Farbinformation zeigen. Aber Du hast ja immer was auszusetzen, daher nehme ich das so hin...

Comment: a) "Weniger detailreich" könnte man zwar behaupten, macht aber inhaltlich keinen Unterschied, es bleibt dabei, dass es eine Vorstellung ist. Detailreich ist eine Einschränkung, eine Konkretisierung. Sich etwas vorstellen ist also abstrakter, die Oberkategorie. Das ist eine Relation. Da die Mathematik, inklusive der Idee der Menge, sich aus der Beschreibung der Realität ergeben hat ist der Versuch, Mathematik als akademische Spinnerei zu desavourieren freundlich, aber energisch zurückzuweisen.

Comment: b) Wenn Du sagst "im Gegensatz zu den anderen Fischen" machst Du eine neue Menge auf, und zwar die der Fische ohne die Tiefseefische. Schwarzweißfotos sind nicht farbärmer als Fotos, sondern nur farbärmer als Fotos ohne Schwarzweißfotos und Tiefseefische können nicht in größeren Tiefen leben als Fische, weil es Fische sind. Dass ich immer etwas auszusetzen habe ist eine Unterstellung. Wenn ich oft etwas auszusetzen habe, dann vielleicht, weil es oft etwas auszusetzen gibt.

Comment: Für einen Sprachlerner macht es einen Unterschied, ob "sich etwas vorstellen" das detailreiche Ausmalen umfasst oder nicht, ob Tiefseefische im dt.-sprachigen Raum zu den Fischen zählen oder nicht und ob man mit Fotos Schwarzweißfotos meinen kann oder nicht. Mit nachlässigen Aussagen zu erklären führt in die Irre und programmiert Missverständnisse vor.

Comment: Als jemand, der Mathematik zumindest im Nebenfach studiert hat, liegt es mir fern, das als Spinnerei abzutun. Es ist nur aus meiner Sicht falsch zu sagen, dass man eine Teilmenge einer Gesamtmenge nicht durch eine Konkretisierung bilden kann (Zitat: "Daher ist es Unsinn zu sagen, dass die Teilmenge mehr/detaillierter, ausgeschmückter ist als die Gesamtmenge, denn sie ist ja ein Teil dieser"). Jede Teilmenge zeichnet sich normalerweise durch besondere Attribute aus - so auch hier. Ich füge einen Absatz in meine Antwort ein. Damit ist das Thema für mich dann auch durch.

Comment: Dass man eine Teilmenge einer Gesamtmenge nicht durch eine Konkretisierung bilden kann bestreite ich nicht, sondern ist genau der Punkt. Das entfernt aber nicht die Teilmenge aus der Gesamtmenge. Basketballspieler können nicht größer sein als Sportler, weil sie Sportler sind. Sie können im Mittel größer sein oder größer als andere Sportler. Du kannst sagen, dass Basketballer große Sportler sind oder dass Ausmalen bildlich ist, emotional, aber nicht bildlicher, emotionaler.

Comment: Ich mag mich irren, aber vermutlich bist Du der einzige, der **nicht** im Geiste ein "als bei einer 'normalen' Vorstellung" ergänzt und somit wieder eine Trennung in zwei disjunkte Mengen vorgenommen hätte... Es sei - ich habe die Antwort überarbeitet.

Comment: Dir ist offenbar aufgefallen, dass die normale Vorstellung in Opposition zu einer unnormalen Vorstellung steht, weswegen Du das *normale* in Anführungsstriche setzt, in der Hoffnung damit das ausdrücken zu können, was Du sagen willst. Diese umständliche Verrenkung beruht gerade auf dem unsachgemäßen Sprachgebrauch. Ich habe auch oft die Türklinke zu diesem Raum der mysteriösen Anführungsstriche schon in der Hand, aber ich versuche sie immer als Warnschüsse wahrzunehmen, dass ich dabei bin vom Pferd zu erzählen; dass ich meine Gedanken offenbar nicht klar gefasst habe. Im 2. Abs. sind noch …

Comment: … immer 5 Vergleiche der Teilmenge mit der Gesamtmenge, aber es ist auf einem guten Weg, inzwischen. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63999/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-thorsten-dittmar).

Answer (score 0):

Für mich wird die Bedeutung anhand des unterscheidenden Teils deutlich "stellen" ist tendenziell konkreter, objektiver und verbindlicher als "malen" was ich eher freier, künstlerischer, unverbindlicher werte.

Answer (score -1):

Mit a) meint sich etw. ausmalen "anschaulich darstellen, schildern" **im Gross.**

Mit b) meint dass die Erste, d.h. "sich etw. vorstellen" (**im ein feiner Sinn.**)

"Sich etw. ausmalen" subsumiert "sich etw. vorstellen."

Comment: Hast Du was getrunken?